# SMSS 'Invalid column name'

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, ssms

Before you reprimand me about how 'this has been asked here:', I'd like to point out I did indeed google. I even went to page 3 in some cases. *shudders*

So here's the deal:
I'm trying to audit a database we have, setting triggers for `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` statements for several tables. The triggers are created, and linked, succesfully. Each trigger executes a stored-procedure that inserts required data into our **tick_audit** table.

This information is:

- user_account; to store *who* changed something
- client_id; to store which client had their data changed
- date_time; the date of the edit
- table_name; the name of the table that was changed
- table_record_id; the *id* of the record that was changed
- descr; a description of *why* something was changed
- remote_ip_address; so we can keep tabs where something was changed (internal or external)

The table also has a PRIMARY_KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT *id* field.

When I try to create the stored-procedure

```
create procedure update_tick_user
@UserId         varchar(32),
@ClientId       varchar(32),
@Table          varchar(64),
@TableRecord    varchar(512),
@Descr          varchar(128),
@RemoteIP       varchar(16)
as
begin
    insert into tick_audit ('user_account', 'client_id', 'date_time', 'table_name', 'table_record_id', 'descr', 'remote_ip_address')
    values
    (@UserId, @ClientId, getdate(), @Table, @TableRecord, @Descr, @RemoteIP)
end;
```

I get the following error(s):

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_tick_user, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'user_account'.

This repeats for each column. When I run

```
exec sp_columns tick_audit
```

I get all the columns from **tick_audit**, and even copying their names into the column-fields for the insert, I get the above-mentioned errors. I even get the errors when I simply run

```
insert into tick_audit 
('user_account', 'client_id', 'date_time', 'table_name', 'table_record_id', 'descr', 'remote_ip_address')
values
('', '', getdate(), '', '', '', '')
```

Whenever I try an insert, update or delete on a different table, I get no errors. Is there anything I could try to find out if there's a fault in my table, or some super-secret hocus-pocus, ritual-esque method?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Drop the table (On my feet, many many times), re-create it.
- Google for three hours
- Asked my co-workers
- Put on my thinking cap
- Check if columns actually exists (through exec, select)

Crossing my fingers and hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `'` to make `insert` as below

```
 insert into tick_audit (user_account, client_id, date_time, table_name, table_record_id, descr, remote_ip_address)
 values (@UserId, @ClientId, getdate(), @Table, @TableRecord, @Descr, @RemoteIP)
```

Comment: I derped so hard. I missed that SQL-Editors don't need single-quotes. Been using too much SQL in Notepad++, Eclipse etc.
The little things..

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes arround column names.

```
create procedure update_tick_user
@UserId         varchar(32),
@ClientId       varchar(32),
@Table          varchar(64),
@TableRecord    varchar(512),
@Descr          varchar(128),
@RemoteIP       varchar(16)
as
begin
    insert into tick_audit (user_account, client_id, date_time, table_name, table_record_id, descr, remote_ip_address)
    values
    (@UserId, @ClientId, getdate(), @Table, @TableRecord, @Descr, @RemoteIP)
end;
```

Comment: @AndriyM I have changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets instead of quotes:

```
insert into tick_audit ([user_account], [client_id], [date_time], [table_name], [table_record_id], [descr], [remote_ip_address])
values (@UserId, @ClientId, getdate(), @Table, @TableRecord, @Descr, @RemoteIP)
```

Single quote are for literals. For delimiting object names you should use brackets or double quotes but you can use double quotes only when `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is set to `ON`.